# Display variable in one class in another VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iboutlet

I try to import contacts in one class set up to do that.  If there are none, however, I want to set a label outlet in a totally separate View Controller to say "None found".

Basically, I want send a message in one class to another but for some reason am drawing a blank.

Following does not not throw an error but also does not set label so is not working.

VC.h:

```
//wired to label in VC in storyboard:

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *noneFound;

@end
```

---

request.m

```
//class that does request

#import "VC.h"

NSString *result = @"none found";
VC* vc;
vc.noneFound.text = result;
```

There must be an obvious way to do this.  Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Your *vc is not being initilized?

Comment: Yes, or loading it from the Mainboard, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use strong instead of weak in property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *noneFound;
```

Answer (score -1):

Although nothing wrong setting a label of a view controller from outside the VC but I would not recommend doing that. MVC architecture governs this.

UI components should not be exposed to header file unless and until it is business logic demand. Its like someone else is taking decision on behalf of view controller. I would suggest to put the IBOutlet in .m file of your VC.

Now, to link request class with your VC, use any of the existing design patters - blocks, delegates, notification, target-action etc. [Refer to Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/DesignPatterns.html)

Once link is there, pass on the value from request class to VC and then within VC ensure that **UI is always updated on MAIN thread.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you be more specific on Now, to link request class with your VC, use any of the existing design patters - blocks, delegates, notification, target-action etc.

Comment: Well, this is bit broader discussion now. I've updated my answer with Apple documentation reference. Basically you need to understand the right way of connecting a VC with other application modules like networking, utilities, other VCs etc.

Comment: I am familiar with the various patterns.  I was hoping there would be a simple obvious way to do this.  What I may do is move the method to the class behind the VC and have it access the data in a different file.

Comment: I would define a protocol between the VC and request class and then set VC as delegate for request class and once request class is done with data fetch it will tell so to its delegate along with the fetched data. It would then be delegate' responsibility to take a decision on fetched data set. In your case, if there is no data one of the label would be set to "none found". So, this way no one but VC knows the underneath UI business logic.

Answer (score -3):

You can always use NSUserDefaults

To save:

```
NSString *valueToSave = @"someValue";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To load:

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];
```